# Return a row or column of maximum/minimum values of an array

Tags: python, arrays, max, row

I'm new to python and this site, so excuse me in advance for my poor style of asking and formatting a question:

Given a numpy array that consists of x rows and y columns, where the elements are values like this:

```
 x=       1 2 3 4 5
          5 1 7 2 0.5   y=1
          2 3 1 5 6     y=2
```

The result I want is: (5,3,7,5,6)

Which command allows me to receive a row/an array of those maximum values?

Thanks !

Comment: Look at the example given in the first answer of the marked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.max(axis=0)`

The axis keyword specifies the dimension of the array that will be collapsed, rather than the dimension that will be returned. So specifying axis=0 means that the first axis will be collapsed: for two-dimensional arrays, this means that values within each column will be aggregated.

Taken from [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.04-computation-on-arrays-aggregates.html).